# virtualbox: guest linux mint copied text cannot be pasted to windows 7 host with mouse button click

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

I am using virtualbox 5.1.30 with host windows 7 64 bit and guest linux mint 18.2 64 bit. I would like to achieve very simple/quick data transfer through clipboard between host and guest by using mouse to select/copy/paste, however, I cannot achieve this effect.

More specifically, using mouse to copy things from host windows 7 to guest linux mint is fine, but going from linux mint to windows, one has to use menu edit -> copy in linux program and then menu edit-paste in windows program to make clipboard work, which is not convenient.

I used to successfully set what I want when I just started using virtualbox as a newbie, but when I reinstall the guest system after I am apt in installing it, it does not work any more. This is very frustrating, has anybody else met with this issue? Anybody has any idea how to possibly resolve it?

Comment: Do you have the Guest Additions installed on the guest system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems in linux, terminal and os has their separate clipboard systems. In order to copy selected text from terminal to os, one might need to click on an entry in the terminal preference to get the two connected.